# Try and Catch User Input causes variables to be uninitialized

Tags: java, variables, input, initialization, try-catch

**EDIT: Okay after fixing the try catch error I get a problem in the `catch {..` when it prints.
**, Basically when I say I want to play again it continues the game as it should but it also prints the first `catch` and then asks for an input at line 23.

```
if (decision.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        {
            ai = (int)(Math.random()*101);
            System.out.println("From 0 to 100, what number do you think I have generated?");

            tryCatch = true;
            loop = true;
            rtrn = true;

            while (tryCatch == true)    
            {   
                while (loop == true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        guess = Integer.parseInt(iConsole.nextLine());
                        if (guess >= 0)
                        {
                            loop = false;
                        }
                    }

                    catch (NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                    }

                    catch (InputMismatchException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again!");
                    }
                }
```

Hi this is my first post so if I get the code formatting on the forum wrong I'll edit it.

Right now I'm coding a game in java eclipse where the cpu generates a number and the user has to guess it. I am using the scanner class for most of this. What I am having trouble doing is creating a try catch to check the user input if it is a valid Integer.

What ends up happening is that the code block below it doesn't recognize the already-initialized variable.

```
package ics3U;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class highLow
{
    static public void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        String name;
        String decision;
        String decision2;
        int ai;
        int guess;
        int counter = 1;
        boolean fullGame = true;
        boolean tryCatch = true;
        boolean rtrn = true;

        Scanner iConsole = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Hello! Welcome to HiLo!");
        System.out.println("What is your full name?");

        name = iConsole.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Hello " + name + "! Would you like to play?");
        decision = iConsole.nextLine();

        while (fullGame == true)
        {
            if (decision.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
            {
                ai = (int)(Math.random()*101);
                System.out.println("From 0 to 100, what number do you think I have generated?");

                tryCatch = true;
                rtrn = true;

                while (tryCatch == true)    
                {   
                    try
                    {
                        guess = Integer.parseInt(iConsole.nextLine());
                    }

                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                    }

                    while (guess != ai)
                    {
                        if (guess < ai)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Too low!");
                            guess = iConsole.nextInt();
                        }

                        else if (guess > ai)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Too high!");
                            guess = iConsole.nextInt();
                        }
                        counter = counter + 1;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Correct! You guessed it after " + counter + " tries!");
                    counter = ((counter - counter)+1);
                    System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");

                    while (rtrn == true)
                    {
                        decision2 = iConsole.next(); //finally..

                        if (decision2.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
                        {
                            fullGame = true;
                            tryCatch = false;
                            rtrn = false;
                            break; //do-while may be needed, have to bypass catch, 'break' works after restating value of tryCatch & rtrn
                        }

                        else if (decision2.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Goodbye.");
                            fullGame = false;
                            tryCatch = false;
                            rtrn = false;
                            iConsole.close();
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Sorry?");
                        }
                    }

                    /*catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                    }

                    catch (NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                    }
                    //More specific Exceptions, turn this on later              
                    catch (InputMismatchException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again!");
                    }*/
                }
            }

            else if (decision.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
            {
                System.out.println("Goodbye.");
                fullGame = false;
                tryCatch = false;
                rtrn = false;
                iConsole.close();
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry?");
                decision = iConsole.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to tell us about syntax errors in a 300 line code block like this, please add comments detailing where they are.

Comment: Also, it's always best to post the actual and entire error message.

Comment: As a side note, you generally should not catch `Exception` unless there are other possible exceptions that could be thrown, and even then you should specify what you are expecting to occur. For instance, in your scenario, you would catch `NumberFormatException` because the user could enter "dog" into the console.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know I had to post that, but yeah what fireshadow said is right. I'm just checking that the user inputted a valid integer.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `continue` statement in your catch block.  That way, if the user enters something that's not an integer and parsing fails, it will immediately try again rather than trying to run the rest of the loop.

```
try
{
    guess = Integer.parseInt(iConsole.nextLine());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
    continue; // jump to beginning of loop
}
```

Comment: wait...so if I use `continue;` I do not need a while loop?

Comment: You will still need the while loop.  But if the user enters something that's not a number, you should try to read another number, not keep going.  That's what the continue is for.

Answer (score 0):

Since the statements are in a try block there's a chance that they will fail, and your program has a chance of trying to use a non-initialized variable. The solution is to initialize the variables to a default value that makes sense, i.e.,

```
int guess = -1; // some default value
```

You should also wrap the while loop around the try/catch block. Don't let the program progress until inputted data is valid.

```
boolean validGuess = false;
while (!validGuess) {
  // prompt user for input here
  try {
    guess = Integer.parseInt(iConsole.nextLine());
    if (/* .... test if guess is valid int */ ) {
      validGuess = true;
    } 
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      // notify user of bad input, that he should try again
  }
}
```

You could even encapsulate all of this into its own method if you need to do similar things throughout the program.

Comment: I tried doing: 'int guess = 0;'  it removes all the errors but then it really doesn't catch anything for some odd reason. Also it seems make some of the blocks of code under it "true" resulting in random prints of output that should not show up unless triggered by the circumstance.

Comment: You should also wrap the while loop around the try/catch block. Don't let the program progress until inputted data is valid.

Comment: I'm not sure what I would put in `if (/* .... test if guess is valid int */ ) ` if I'm checking the user input with `guess = Integer.parseInt(iConsole.nextLine());`.

Comment: usually you'll check that guess isn't below some minimum, I'll guess that you want it > 0, and that it's not above some maximum -- that it's in the appropriate range for a proper answer.

Comment: Okay I was just about to say that lol, I did `if (guess >= 0) {....` and it works. I'm close to done but what's happening is that when I ask to play again and the user inputs "yes" it will print `"From 0 to 100, what number do you think I have generated?"` but then it thinks it is an exception and prints the catch. I have a conclusion so tell me if this would work, chance the General Exception to a general one.

Comment: Basically this is what happens: `Would you like to play again?
/*yes*/
From 0 to 100, what number do you think I have generated?
Invalid input. Please try again.` It doesn't crash or create an exception but it takes in the "yes" as the guess input and it prints the catch notification.

Comment: @Amirsan: you need to edit your main question to tell everyone this clarification of  your problem, you need to post the exact error message and you need to indicate which line throws the exception in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving all your code after the catch block (in the loop) inside the try block after this line

```
guess = Integer.parseInt(iConsole.nextLine());
```

As you currently have it, anytime there is an exception in the parseInt, it will still try to process the unassigned **guess** instead of restarting the loop.

Comment: I did that, and it works. The thing is I will never know where the Exception occurs as my teacher stated. So I'm trying to isolate the exception and catch it. Also I've gotten a few errors from it and it's hard to trace through all the code to find where the exception is occurring.